# Using Task.Delay inside an Azure Durable Function Activity

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Is it OK to use Task.Delay inside an Azure Durable Function **Activity** like this?

I am polling storage for data that should arrive within 20-30 seconds or so.

```
 while (requestAccepted && retryCount < 8)
        {
            object savedData = await DataManagementService.GetSessionData(processSessionId);

            if (savedData != null && savedData.GetType().GetProperties().Any())
            {
                return true;
            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            retryCount++;
        }
```

The function timers feature using `context.CreateTimer`, explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers), is only available to Azure **Orchestration** Function and not **Activity** Function.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly OK to use `Task.Delay()` as long as you're happy paying for the dead time while the function's waiting and you know that it will complete before it times out.

However, a better option is to move the `GetSessionData()` call into an activity function, convert this polling function to an orchestrator so you can replace `Task.Delay()` with `context.CreateTimer()` and invoke it from the main orchestrator via `context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync()`.

Comment: sure I also thought about refactoring this in the way your described but found CreateTimer supports timeout scenario and doesn't really do polling scenario. I could extend it further to an external wait pattern but that is far too glamorous for what I'm doing. ;o)

Comment: Just remember to use it in an **activity**, not in the **orchestration** directly. The latter wouldn't work, as things currently stand.